# Operator that adds the correct spread to <label> attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions that both set different values. In the markup, how do I set the  attribute to have the correct spread. I know how to do this with the standard ternary operator but I don't want to copy the same code for everything that goes under the  attribute, as it's wrapped inside of it.

```
  const labelAttributes = ['checkbox'].includes(type)
    ? keyboardEvents({ space: () => helpers.setValue(!field.value) })
    : null;

  const labelAttributesRadio = ['radio'].includes(type)
    ? keyboardEvents({ space: () => helpers.setValue(value) })
    : null;

return (
        {type == 'radio' ? (
          <label {...labelAttributesRadio}>
        ) : (
          <label {...labelAttributes}>
        )}
          // Removed a lot more content but don't want to have to copy it twice within the operator
          <Field>
          </Field>
          <span>
          </span>
        </label>
```

)

Comment: more code is needed. Unsure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial If the type is radio then I want it use the ...labelAttributesRadio. The label then has lot more content inside of it so I'm trying to not copy the same code, as the only difference is the the label spread. Do you want me to provide more code?

Comment: Why not assign it to labelAttributes only and use that. That way you won't have a condition in render.
`const labelAttributes = type === 'checkbox'
    ? keyboardEvents({ space: () => helpers.setValue(!field.value) })
    : (type === 'radio' ? keyboardEvents({ space: () => helpers.setValue(value) }) : null);`